# TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData' parameter 2 is not type of 'Blob'

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to writing test case for angular unit testing.
Facing issue while writing the test case for below typescript.

**editflag.component.ts**

```
private create(){
    const formData = this.constructFormData(this.flagClone,this.files.file,this.files.file,this.files.file.name);
    this.flagService.createFlag(formData).subscribe((response: any) => {
        if(response.label === 1 ){
            this.editFlagDialog.close(create);
        } else {
            this.message.showNotification('Failed to create.');
        }
    }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(error);
            this.message.showNotification('Failed to create.');
    });
}

private update(){
    const formData = this.constructFormData(this.flagClone,this.files.file,this.files.file,this.files.file.name);
    this.flagService.updateFlag(this.flagClone.id,formData).subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.editFlagDialog.close(edit);
        }
    }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(error);
            this.message.showNotification('Failed to update.');
    });
}

public constructFormData(meta, flagFile, thumbnail, filename): FormData {
    const formData = new FormData();
    
    formData.append('meta', this.addJson(meta));
    formData.append('logo', flagFile, filename);
    formData.append('thumbnail', thumbnail);
    return formData;
}

public addJson(jsonData): Blob {
    return new Blob ([JSON.stringfy(jsonData)], {type: 'application/json'});
}
```

The test case which I have written are as follows:
**editFlag.spec.ts**

```
let mockFlagService;

const testData: Client = {
        id: null, //string
        description: null,  //string
        url: null,      //string
        client: null
};

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        EditFlagComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        HttpClient,
        HttpHandler,
        {provide: MatDialog, useValue: {} },
        {provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
        {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {testData} },
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
    mockFlagService = TestBed.inject(FlagService);
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditFlagComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  
it('should call update',() => {
    const flagSpy = spyOn(mockFlagService, 'updateFlag').and.returnValue(of(testData));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.update()
    expect(flagSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But I am getting this error *TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData' parameter 2 is not type of 'Blob'*